# Google Analytics exceptions and sessions correlation

Tags: android, session, google-analytics

Since last week (Jul 25 till Jul 29 2016), I am seeing a huge rise in sessions particularly number of sessions < 1 second. I have changed nothing in my app since the 2 weeks.

I have attached a comparison screen of how the sessions used to look prior to the week mentioned. And all data seemed good. 
[image: Sessions comparison of 2 weeks.]

UPDATE:

There was an issue and I was logging the exception to Google Analytics and specifying `setFatal` to `true`. Since this was happening just after the Google Analytics initialization, I suspect that the session was being counted. Counter question. What is the relation to Google Analytics exception throwing with sessions?

Comment: Have you looked into whether these sessions are genuine? Dig into the hostname dimensions (either as a secondary dimension or in a custom report); 99% of hostnames other than your website are spam